# Symfony 3.4 form login redirects to index page and dosent authenticate

Tags: php, symfony

I want to go to the admin page. I go to Url /admin. I get redirected to the login page. And now the Problem, I fill the form click on login and get redirected to the index page not on /admin and im not authenticated.

I using symfony3.4 and form_login. I've looked in the Profiler and it seems to me the the login in is working but i get logged out immediately after that.

Sessions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLIMG.jpg

Security while Post request on /login: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka9tB.jpg

on index Page after Login: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wR2w.jpg

config/security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: $2y$13$xAvoz5UgaciMjR2wCashoOcdOku13ieKsRPMlNh7.uimmDmojkYCi
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~
            logout_on_user_change: true
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

routing.yml

```
login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    path: /login
logout:
    path: /logout

easyadmin.entryPoint:
    path: /admin/entryPoint
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Admin:entryPoint }

easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: '@AdminBundle/Controller/AdminController.php'
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
```

SecurityController

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('@Admin/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

login.html.twig

```
{% extends '@App/base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('admin_bundle_login') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    <form id="login-form" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <div id="username">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>
        </div>
        <div id="password">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"/>
        </div>
        {% if error %}
            <div id="login-error">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <button type="submit" id="login-submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

dev.log

```
[2019-03-31 12:32:58] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AdminBundle\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/admin/login","method":"GET"} []
[2019-03-31 12:32:58] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-03-31 12:32:58] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"ff647b","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/_wdt/ff647b","method":"GET"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:11] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AdminBundle\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/admin/login","method":"POST"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:11] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"admin"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:11] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:11] request.INFO: Matched route "index". {"route":"index","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"index"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/","method":"GET"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:11] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-03-31 12:33:12] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"03981c","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/_wdt/03981c","method":"GET"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:12] request.INFO: Matched route "ajaxProvider". {"route":"ajaxProvider","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::ajaxProviderAction","_route":"ajaxProvider"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/slots.json","method":"GET"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:12] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-03-31 12:33:13] request.INFO: Matched route "ajaxProvider". {"route":"ajaxProvider","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::ajaxProviderAction","_route":"ajaxProvider"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/slots.json","method":"GET"} []
[2019-03-31 12:33:13] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
```

I expect to get authenticated after login

Comment: cookies working alright?

Comment: i dont know how they must work but i have the Problem on multiple device

Comment: I have rethought. Have you tried, after logging in, to just go to the /admin uri? because the index page isn't behind the firewall, thus no user credentials are required

Comment: I get redircted to /login and the debug bar says on every page logged in as anon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your user credentials (the user config of the in memory user provider) to `roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']`

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin:
                    password: $2y$13$xAvoz5UgaciMjR2wCashoOcdOku13ieKsRPMlNh7.uimmDmojkYCi
                    roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']   # <-- this!
```

**old/original answer**

as far as I can tell, the normal approach is to put the login form under the firewall it's supposed to be covered by, that means, adding the following to the access_control section of your security.yaml (order matters!):

```
access_control: 
   - { path: /admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

(the last line you should already have)

you also need to change your login route to `/admin/login` (in the routing.yaml)

reasoning: check_path and login_path are usually the same. but the requirements differ (source: [form_login authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#form-login-authentication)):

> **login_path:** This path must be accessible by a normal, un-authenticated user, else you may create a redirect loop.
>
> **check_path:** Be sure that this URL is covered by your main firewall (i.e. don't create a separate firewall just for check_path URL).

Comment: Result is the same but i forget to say if i use the wrong credentials on login. I get no Error Message. I just don't get redirected

Comment: have you checked the var/log/(dev|prod).log if there's output?

Comment: I have added the dev.log

Comment: it's just weird ;o/

Comment: Any other ideas ?

Comment: @FabianK. maybe this changes nothing, but have you tried turning your `roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'` (in security yaml in memory user provider) to `roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']` ?